# Sendgrid email not sent + no "recent activity" + no exceptions

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am configuring Sendgird for the first time and I want to send emails using c#.

This is the code I am using, and I know for a fact that it is working because I can use it with another sendgird account that was configured by the IT department:

```
    public static async void SendEmailsToUser(string[] mailAddresses, string subject, string fullHtmlEmail)
    {            
        var sendgridMessage = new SendGrid.SendGridMessage();
        foreach (var emailAddress in mailAddresses)
            sendgridMessage.AddTo(emailAddress);

        sendgridMessage.From = new MailAddress("blah@blah.com", "blah");
        sendgridMessage.Subject = subject;
        sendgridMessage.Html = fullHtmlEmail;

        var transportWeb = new SendGrid.Web("sendgrid_key");
        await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(sendgridMessage);
    }
```

The code generates no exceptions, but I don't receive the test email and the sendgrid webpage shows no trace of recent activity.

The only idea that comes to mind is that maybe I have not generated the API key correctly? (Settings -> API keys -> Generate new -> full permissions)

Comment: It looks like if you set the wrong "sent from" email address, the email is not sent...

Comment: `sendgridMessage.From =` this should be `.To` not `.From`